# Do plastic sheds require a foundation?

Tags: shed

Do I need a foundation for [this type of shed](http://www.homedepot.com/Storage-Organization-Sheds-Garages-Outdoor-Storage-Sheds-Plastic/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ1xilZbu8z/R-100652232/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053), or can I just put it on level ground?

Comment: FWIW, I have a 6'x8' plastic shed on a gravel base.  It's been there for 6.5 years and I'm starting to notice some lean.  I'd recommend a better base than just the ground.

Comment: What's the frost depth in your climate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [assembly instructions](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/be/be5af1ec-1c7d-4f60-940c-861e678476ae.pdf) state:

> Recommended surfaces for installation include cement or treated wood deck style surfaces.

So it should be installed on a level platform of some kind that will support the weight of the shed and its contents.

It wouldn't be a good idea just to use level ground as you'll have problems with moisture, rodents etc (as Eric Petroelje points out in his comment). You may well also find that the shed will sink unevenly into the ground making it difficult, if not impossible to use.

Comment: Recommended is not required, however.

Comment: beat me to it ! :) it's probably not "absolutely required" to have it on a foundation but it's VERY strongly recommended. Putting it right on the ground will lead to long term issues, most notably as you start putting more and more weight in it.

Comment: +1, Even if he had ground level enough to install it on, he's going to have lots of problems with moisture, bugs, rodents, etc. if there isn't some kind of deck or slab underneath it.

Comment: @Eric - Updated answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I got pea gravel and spread it onto bare ground after I raked it. I have had my shed for 4 years. It is not sinking. YMMV but I don't think you need to lay a concrete surface. On older, wood sheds it was recommended due to rot, but in a Rubbermaid shed I don't think it is necessary.